# php strtotime and working out years?

Tags: php, time

I have a date stored in my mysql database and I can workout the days since the date like so,

```
 ceil(time() - strtotime($account['joined']) / 60 / 60 / 24 % 365);
```

But how can I work out the years, since years is the highest format of time, since after that it is millenia and such?

The variable is one such as:

```
2011-10-06 22:01:57
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `$account['joined']` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date("Y")`

```
<?php 
$time = strtotime("1 Jan 2001 1:11:11"); 
echo "Years since time: ".(date("Y") - date("Y", $time));
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/220fe/1

Comment: Will this work for minutes, hours, seconds etc, and is it better to use it than my example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mysql database to get the timespan.

You could use `DATEDIFF` in your query to substract the joined-date from the current date and you can get the timespan this way.

This function is explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Hope it helps

Comment: Thought about this but my website is heavy on database calls, and take up alot of the overhead whereas rendering php doesn't so would like to use php, thanks though :)

Comment: There are benefits when coding on the database side: Reduced errors in time calculations as everything is based on one clock (the database clock if separate from the webserver), minimized traffic (not much passing of parameters), and faster queries. You can speed up querying if you place often run statements in a stored procedure. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208976/are-stored-procedures-faster-for-simple-queries)

Answer (score 1):

You always can use `date("Y", $timestamp)`,

and for your issue you can use date_diff,

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can perform the calculation from the MySQL side, use the built-in [date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). For example assuming that table T contains a date column D and you want to compare it against the current date in terms of number of days:

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, D, CURDATE()) AS 'days_elapsed'
FROM T
```

You can change the first argument in TIMESTAMPDIFF to any of the following: FRAC_SECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.